# Universal Windows Plateform And Live SDK

Tags: windows-10, live-sdk, uwp

I have a problem. I recently installed VS 2015 and Windows 10 on my computer.
Having Universal Apps are amazing and I plan to convert some of my programs on UWP.
But I have a problem. In one of my programs, I allow the user to save its datas on its OneDrive. And if OneDrive is unavailable, the datas are stored on local devices.
And when OneDrive is available, the newly stored datas are pushed to OneDrive. Synchronisation in fact.
So it is the problem. In the UWP dll named Universal.Live I have installed Live SDK 6 with Nuget. During the package installation, there is some work done to see if the Live SDK is compatible with UWP.
Great ! It's compatible and successfully installed.
But when I wrote

using Microsoft.Live;

The name is not recognized. And if I use the class LiveAuthClient which is in the namespace, it isn't recognized too...
This is a real problem :( Any ideas ?

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions and I can provide more details when I get home from work.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue adding the Live SDK to my app. For some reason the Package.JSON isn't correctly resolving and downloading the package (or recognizing it).

Either way, just add the DLL to your references the old fashioned way. Personally, I'd just add it to a console app (not using the new Project.json package), get it from NUGET, and grab the DLL from the Packages.

After you have the DLL:

1. Right click on References
2. Add Reference -> Browse...
3. Find the DLL and add it. ("...\\packages[LiveSdk]...")
4. It works!

Download it from here, Compile it, and grab the desktop SDK:

https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Windows

You can also download the msi, install it, figure out where the DLL is installed to and grab it from there:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42552

Comment: I installed the Live SDK msi and was able to select Live SDK from the Universal Windows\Extensions section in the Add Reference dialog box. Worryingly, Live SDK did appear greyed out in the dialog and it gave a compatibility warning when I selected it, but it still added the reference and appears to be working fine; I’ve tested with a release build and ran the app through the certification checks.

Comment: I added the dll aswell. And it will work in debug mode. But in release  mode and when published to the store it will crash... Any Solution to this?

Comment: Are you sure it's crashing due to the LiveSDK? Mine was working correctly when I released the app, but I did encounter some issues with the ParseSDK. For debugging in release, it might be best to surround each of the methods in your VM with a `Try{}Catch{}` and outputting the exception.Message and `exception.StackTrace` into a `MessageDialog` so you can easily view the error information.

Answer (score 1):

According to this GitHub issue, LiveSDK isn't supposed to be used for Universal Windows Platform apps: https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Windows/issues/58

Instead we should use these SDKs that cover the same functionality:

- Mail/Calendar/Contacts: https://dev.outlook.com/
- Files/OneDrive: https://dev.onedrive.com/